# Angular 6 Change Styles Using Renderer2 of a different column within ngFor

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have added columns to a table using ngFor. when user clicks on `<td>` it opens a Dialog box and it return some values. Based on selected values it changes the background-color of that particular `<td>` using Renderer2 .Based on that returned values I want to change the color of some other `<td>` as well. Returned values has the `item` objects of `<td>` s that I want to make the changes. How can I achieve that?

```
<td 
   *ngFor="let item of items; index as i"
   (click)="openDialog(someVal)"
    #someVal
>
```

Component.ts

```
  openDialog(someVal): void {

      // Some Conditions .................

       this.rd.setStyle(someVar, 'background-color', this.colorCode);
    });
  }
```

Comment: Hi, Welcome on Stackoverflow are you able to proivde more Code from the openDialog?

Comment: It returns the item objects of <td> s that I want to make the changes. I updated my description

Answer (score 0):

You can use Directive : You can define your own directives to attach behavior to
`<td>` element in the DOM.

```
<td [dialog]="someVal"
*ngFor="let item of items; index as i"
 >
```

Class

```
 import { fromEvent  } from 'rxjs';

 @Directive({
 selector: '[dialog]'
 })
 export class DialogDirective{

 public action: ElementRef ;

  constructor( elementRef: ElementRef<HTMLElement>) {
  this.action = elementRef ;
  }

 @Input() set dialog( someVal : any ) {

 // Some Conditions ...

 // Subscription
 fromEvent(this.action.nativeElement, 'click').pipe(
  .....

 }
```